# Statistic equivalent to F statistic with several factors?

Tags: self-study, anova, ancova, f-statistic, permutation-test

In class we learned that if we want to perform a randomisation/permutation test on the hypothesis:

$H_0: y_{ij} = \mu_i + e_{ij}$ vs. $H_1: y_{ij} = \mu + e_{ij}$

Where we calculate the test $F$ statistic for each permuted data, it can be shown that for this simple case $F=\frac{(RSS_{reduced}-RSS_{complete})/q}{RSS_{complete}/(n-p)}$ is equivelent to the test statistic $\sum_i \frac{T_i^2}{n_i}$ where $T_i$ is the total for group $i$, and $n_i$ is the number of elements in group $i$. They are equivalent because they both have the same ordering with respect to any two permuted samples $X_1$ and $X_2$.

I have no problem understanding/proving this, however when going over a past exam a slightly more general question is asked. If instead we want to test the model with $3$ factors:

$H_0: y_{ijkl}=\beta_i^1 + \beta_j^2 + \beta_k^3 + e_{ijkl}$    vs    $H_1: y_{ijkl}=\beta_i^1 + \beta_j^2 + e_{ijkl}$

Then it asks for an equivelent test statistic in regards to permutation testing. We still have the same formula for the test statistic $F$, but what is an equivalent statistic?

For each test statistic we permute the labelings of the third factor while keeping the other factors tied to the observations. We then calculate the $F$ statistic for the permuted data, and compare the distribution of these permuted statistics with the data's original statistic.

I thought of using $\frac{1}{RSS_{complete}}$ however I wasn't able to show this preserved ordering for any two permuted samples.